# Accessing workbooks without have tenant roles?

Tags: azure-log-analytics, azure-monitor-workbooks

We have a set of log analytics workspaces, each with some workbooks. One workspace for each project. We need to grant the administrators access to the workbooks for general monitoring. I have assigned the as owner on the log analytics, but hey only see their own workbooks. They cannot see the one I created. When I read this article it states you need:

Global administrator
Security administrator
Security reader
Report reader
Application administrator

But I am sure I have misunderstood you need those privileges' to show workspaces to system administrators. Anyone know how to manage access for a single workspace and related workbooks?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-use-azure-monitor-workbooks#prerequisites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where did you save your workbooks?  when you saved, you would have picked sub+resource group.  do those users have access to query resources in the sub+resource group you saved yours to?

the workspace RBAC controls access to the database itself, but where you save your resources (the workbooks) determines if other users can see them or not.

If you think of all this as a file system,

1. think of the workspace as a specific database file,  "C:\rg1\workspace A\database.db"
2. subscription sub as a drive letter, "sub a" = "C:", "sub b" as "D:", etc
3. resource group as a folder inside a sub ("D:\rg2")

Just because you granted a user RBAC access to #1, doesn't mean they can see things you saved into #3.

*by default* when you save a workbook it would *try* to save it to the same sub+rg as the workspace itself, but depending on RBAC users might not be able to create resources there.
(with the analogy above, the default setting would be to try save new workbooks into "C:\rg1" where the workspace is, if you have write access on that RG)

Additionally, if you created your workbooks at some point in the past, you would have had the option to save them as "shared" or "private" (aka "my workbooks", which we're working on deprecating because this confuses everyone).  Make sure you didn't save yours to "my workbooks", as only *the author* can see those.  you'd have to use the "move to shared" command in the editing toolbar to make sure your workbooks are shared so the others can see them.